# Applications of universal coefficient theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm not really sure what I want to ask here, which isn't a great start for a question, but nonetheless...

I am wondering if there are some nice results that we can get from considering (co)homology with coefficients in an arbitrary abelian group. For example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem) states that

> ...it is common to take $A$ to be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so that coefficients are modulo 2.

Is this just for ease of computation, or is there some useful results that can be gathered (for any abelian group, not just modulo 2)?

**Edit**: I was thinking about this question because the cohomlogy of the projective spaces in the mod 2 case just become $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$  - compare to the cohomlogy with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$,where the odd coefficients are zero

Comment: Well, $3$-torsion in homology is not seen in homology modulo $2$...

Comment: @Mariano - well...yes! I guess I am after useful *applications*

Comment: Algebraic topology is often done "one prime at a time".  That is, you check out what happens mod p for each p, you check what happens rationally, and then you try to stitch the pieces back together to a coherent picture.  This began with Serre's C-theory, which was the framework for his method of computing homotopy groups of spheres.  Certainly the UCT played a role here!

Comment: Coefficients in arbitrary abelian groups comes up naturally in *obstruction theory*, which is a fairly pragmatic, computable theory for solving "every day" algebraic topology problems.  The first developments in obstruction theory were things like Stiefel-Whitney classes, which are UCT images of things called "primary obstruction classes".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why homology with coefficients?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619544/why-homology-with-coefficients)