# $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients in homology

Tags: homological-algebra

I don't see the point in using homology and cohomology with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Can you provide some examples for why this is useful?

Comment: One quick reason: a manifold is always Z/2Z orientable. This allows results like Poincare duality to work.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find a reference for this? I tried in Bott-Tu (Differential Forms etc.) and Irapidly noticed that the third book of Fomenko "Modern Geometry" spends lots of words about Z/2 cohomology, but I'm lacking a precise place.

Comment: Have you checked in Massey's Algebraic Topology book, or Bredon's Geometry and Topology book?

Comment: Another (more technical) thing is that it's easier to work in char 2, because you can ignore all signs — which makes many computations much, much easier (say, try to compute homology — or just Euler char — of a real Grassmannian...).

Comment: I asked a similar question - why do we use different coefficient's at all - and there are some interesting responses here:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37148/applications-of-universal-coefficient-theorem

Have a look at Section 3.3 of [Hatcher's Book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) for a nice discussion of Poincare Duality and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody, I found a couple of good examples in your answers: is there a way to "accept" a comment?

Answer (score 15):

1. A lot of times it's easier to work with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients. You don't have to worry about sign and calculations are easier.
2. Field coefficients are nice because there is a precise duality between homology and cohomology, without worrying about the universal coefficient theorem.
3. Knowledge of $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients can help you say things about integral homology. For example, if $H_i(X;\mathbb Z_p)=0$ for all primes $p$, then $H_i(X;\mathbb Z)=0$.
4. Some spaces have a nicer presentation with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients. The cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{RP}^n;\mathbb Z_2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2[x]/x^{n+1}$, whereas the integral cohomology ring is messier to write down.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another one to add to the list: I am currently reading about cohomology operations, in particular the Steenrod squares.

These are functions

$$\operatorname{Sq^i}:H^k(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \to H^{k+i}(X,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$$

which satisfies a whole bunch of [nice properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steenrod_algebra#Axiomatic_characterization) (or axioms depending on how one looks at things)

Adams used these cohomology operations to solve the vector fields on spheres problem.

See the very excellent book by Mosher & Tangora's "Cohomology Operations and Applications in Hommotopy Theory" for the details